# How to make HTML5 element selectively hide sibling elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an HTML5 video player and need to create chapter markers on the scrub bar. The markers are hollow ellipses with transparent centers. I want the markers to hide the progress (scrub) and buffer bars while showing the video.

What I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]

The closest solution I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275708/selectively-hide-background-elements-when-overlayed-with-transparent-div) but I cannot use jquery. Also, since I need cross-browser compatibility, I can't use mix-blend-mode. I've experimented with changing z-index and display attributes and have not gotten the needed results.

For a pared-down working example, please run the code snippet. Thank you, good people.

```js
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
var bufferBar = document.getElementById('buffer');
var divID = document.getElementById('c-markers');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.id = "marker" + i;
  divID.appendChild(anchor);

  var marker = document.getElementById("marker" + i);
  marker.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://i.imgur.com/YTWgnzn.png')";
  marker.style.left = (i * 150) + 'px';

  progress.value = .33;
  bufferBar.value = .66;
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 640px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 0;
}

#player {
  background-color: #252525;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.controls {
  width: 98%;
  height: 80%;
}

.controls .progress-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}

.controls progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.controls progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

.controls progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: transparent;
}

progress.progress-bar,
progress.buffer-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

progress.progress-bar {
  z-index: 1000;
}

progress.buffer-bar {
  z-index: 100;
}

progress.buffer-bar::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

progress.buffer-bar::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

progress.progress-bar::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: red;
}

progress.progress-bar::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: red;
}

progress {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2);
}

progress.progress-bar {
  color: red;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2);
}

#c-markers {
  width: 100%;
}

#c-markers a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 11px;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="section-container">
    <div id="player">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="progress-container">
          <div id="c-markers"></div>
          <progress id="progress" class="progress-bar" value="0" min="0"></progress>
          <progress id="buffer" class="buffer-bar" value="0" min="0"></progress>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: It is safe to assume the blue background/video would be visible through the disks?

Any chance of just tweaking the design?

Comment: Why not just rewrite the solution in the question you linked to as plain old normal JavaScript?

Comment: @MarkHandy: yes, the blue background would be visible through the disks. The client has provided the specifications and I'm not at liberty to tweak.

Comment: @Shaggy The solution from the question link uses a duplicate of the background, which in my case, would be a video. Not viable.

Answer (score 0):

I have fully redesigned your snippet, I think that this is what you want.

Your javascript code (not included) should calculate the width values of the fillers

```css
.markers {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, lightgreen, lightblue);
}

.filler {
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 600px, white 600px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1200px 20px;
  background-position: -600px 0px;
  animation: progress 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes progress {
  from {background-position: -600px 0px;}
    to {background-position:    0px 0px;}
}

#filler1 {
  width: 100px;
}

#filler2 {
  width: 80px;
}

#filler3 {
  width: 260px;
}

.item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="markers">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="filler" id="filler1"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="filler" id="filler2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="filler" id="filler3"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, vals. I'm not sure how I can split the progress and buffer bars into individual lengths, however, since the bars represent the total time duration of the video.